# Can I stop events from being dragged past start and end boundaries?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When events are draggable in fullcalendar, I can drag them up past the start hour and down past the end hour. This happens with a minTime and maxTime configured and when they are not configured (i.e. midnight to midnight). I need events to not be allowed to be dragged past the hour boundaries of the day or configured time range.

I don't see anything in the documentation about stopping this behavior. Has anyone run into this issue and come up with a solution or does anyone have a solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and experimenting, I have discovered the solution to this problem is by using the `containment` option in the [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) plugin.

To stop the behavior described in the question, follow these steps:

1. Search for the function called `draggableSlotEvent`.
2. Under it, find `eventElement.draggable({`.
3. Place the following line as another option: `containment: ".fc-agenda-body table",`

You will now be unable to drag events past the hour boundaries.

Comment: I have this visually working, but the event times still change as if their position is changed. Excellent fix though!

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by `Michael Irigoyen`, doesn't work in my case with `FullCalendar v2.0.0` in week agenda view.

**I have made the following changes in order to make it work:**

**1.** For the time interval drag: The `.fc-agenda-body` selector doesn't exist in agenda week view. In function `draggableSlotEvent` on `eventElement.draggable` I have set the `containment` to `.fc-agenda table`:

```
function draggableSlotEvent(event, eventElement, timeElement) {

    // code

    eventElement.draggable({
        containment: '.fc-agenda table',
        // code
    });
}
```

**2.** For the time interval resize: In function `resizableSlotEvent` on `eventElement.resizable` I have set the `containment` to `table.fc-agenda-slots`:

```
function resizableSlotEvent(event, eventElement, timeElement) {

    // code

    eventElement.resizable({
        containment: 'table.fc-agenda-slots',
        // code
    });
}
```

**3.** All the tables in the calendar MUST not have margin bottom or everything above will fail. So, I changed in the fullcalendar css:

```
.fc-view-agendaWeek table {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

All the changes above restricts time intervals between midnights or minTime/maxTime perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

currently not possible, a new option would need to be created. here is the issue:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=824